# Content on left with image on right in magazine websites

Tags: website-design, layout, content

I came across [the New Yorker website](http://www.newyorker.com) and noticed that in some of the inner category pages, the content is placed on left and the image on the right. This is a structure I see quite often.

Is there any reason behind placing the content on the left and the image on the right?

Please check [this link](http://www.newyorker.com/science/elements) to get a clear idea.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess at the content is king basis. If the feature of the article is an image, I'd place it on the left, as the articles listed are editorials, the content is key and therefore is placed on the left.

UX is not about hard and fast rules, but given the reasoning above and the fact we read left to right in the West, their design decision makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

One can only assume why the New Yorker does this. The only way to know for sure is to contact them and ask.

Here's a few reasons I can think of;

- The New Yorker wants readers to first see the title and intro text, based on [F-shape reading patterns.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/f-shaped-pattern-reading-web-content/)
- The New Yorker's main content is articles, so text is more important than supporting images.

**I'd put the images on the left**

Personally I wouldn't have done this. [The human eye fixes images much faster that written text.](https://uxplanet.org/visual-perception-icons-vs-copy-in-ui-cd8e1a2f8af0) It clashes with the above mentioned F-shaped reading pattern. My eyes want to start left, but are pulled to the images on the right. Very confusing. There's no clear path for my eyes to take because of this.

Answer (score 0):

The F-shape / golden triangle is predicated upon (being Western -reading left to right) and TEXT as content... if you've noticed, CR/LF initiates every line -long or SHORT- at the lefthand side: which means short text has no content to the righthand side - so who would look?! Hence the F shape